# Copy an existing local file to InstallDir with WIX

Tags: wix

I'm creating a WIX installer and I want it to look for a specific local XML file that may or may not be on the user's machine. If it finds it, I want it to simply copy it to the InstallDir together with all the dll's being deployed.

Can this be done w/out a CustomAction?

Something like:

```
        <Property Id="SETTINGSXMLFOUND">
        <DirectorySearch Id="x86FolderLocation" Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]\FolderA\bin">
            <FileSearch Id="My_FileSearch" Name="*.xml" />
        </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>

    <Condition>
        <![CDATA[Installed AND SETTINGSXMLFOUND]]>
        <CopyFile ... </CopyFile>
    </Condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition element can only have Component, Control, Feature, Fragment, PermissionEx or Product as parents. Also CopyFile will only accept Componet or File as Parent. So perhaps a component will work? I did not test this, but this may work:

```
<Component Id="FileCopyComponent" Guid="*">
    <Condition><![CDATA[Installed AND SETTINGSXMLFOUND]]></Condition>
    <CopyFile Id="MyFileCopyId" FileId="MyFileId" DestinationDirectory="MyCopyDir"  />
</Component>
```

Comment: Thank you. This didn't work because of several problems, and I was running out of time, so ended up using a C# CustomAction.